# How to iterate a dictionary based on another dictionary in python?

Tags: python, algorithm, dictionary, data-structures

I have a dictionary having diet information for a week, for which we need to calculate the number of days a customer has consumed a distinct category of food based on the output metadata. The output metadata has the category of food as key and food in the diet as values. The values `1, 0` are boolean indicators denoting whether the customer ate or not, respectively.

Here the customer has consumed both chicken and lamb on Thursday, but while summing we want to count just one day of "Meat". The grouping of categories in the metadata might change in the future, e.g. if the customer eats fish.

Could you please help me to solve this problem?

```
diet = {'chicken' : [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
        'lamb'    : [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1],
        'salad'   : [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1]}

output_metadata = {'Meat'    : ['chicken', 'lamb'],
                   'Veggies' : ['salad'],
                   'Overall' : ['chicken', 'lamb', 'salad']}
```

Desired output is

```
{'Meat': 5, 'Veggies': 4, 'Overall': 6}
```

Comment: Seems like you just need some nested loops.

Comment: What do the numbers 1 and 0 represent? If it's just whether or not they ate the food on that day, it would be better to use `True` and `False`. Using numbers make it seem like they're quantities.

Comment: @Barmar, I have updated the question. Updating True/False looked lengthy, so I didn't. thanks!

Comment: `{k: sum(map(any, zip(*(Diet[f] for f in v)))) for k, v in output_metadata.items()}}`

Comment: Look into pandas

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to check for a non-zero value of any of the selected categories on a different day, you can zip the selected arrays together. For example:

```
def days(diet, categories):
    it = zip(*(diet[c] for c in categories))
    return sum(any(x) for x in it)
```

Now you can build the output dict:

```
output = {k: days(Diet, v) for k, v in output_metadata.items()}
```

As a one-liner (don't actually do this):

```
output = {k: sum(any(x) for x in zip(*(Diet[c] for c in v))) for k, v in output_metadata.items()}
```

But really, what you have is a dataframe in disguise. Consider using the pandas library for something like this. You will be able to select the days and/or categories individually and sum up whatever statistics you want.

Comment: Thanks! but this solution gives the number of times he ate the category of food, but we need number of days in a distinctive way.. suppose he ate lamb and chicken on same day it should be counted as one.

Comment: @vamos3556. I totally rewrote the answer